# Build a custom filter in joomla back end

Tags: php, joomla

I am creating a filter in back end listing page, according to the documentation
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components

but i encountered the error
 Call to a member function get() on a non-object
with the code

```
  $this->items            = $this->get('Items');
  $this->pagination       = $this->get('Pagination');
  $this->state            = $this->get('State');

  //Following variables used more than once
  $this->sortColumn       = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
  $this->sortDirection    = $this->state->get('list.direction');
  $this->searchterms      = $this->state->get('filter.search');
```

in file views / zzz / view.html.php

How is the code working?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The calls like

```
$this->get('State');
```

will invoke the method named

```
public function getState()
```

in the corrensponding model, unless it's otherwise instantiated it would be `models/zzz.php`

The following three lines try to load the values saved by the function populateState() in modellist (from which your `zzz` model inherits) to retrieve the ordering and filter that are set in the model.  But apparently `$this->state` doesn't get set (the above line), so test the output of `getState()` first.

To avoid the error, you can see if state is set:

```
if (isset($this->state)) {
$this->sortColumn       = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
etc...
```

but you should really try to understand why it's not set by debugging the code.